# Postgres generated column silently failing

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am recreating a table which used to be updated by triggers, to the new generated column types.

I'm running into a problem where if the generated column can be `NULL`, they silently fail and get inserted as `NULL`. If the columns are `NOT NULL` the insert fails as a `NOT NULL constraint`.

Both cases fail and don't generate the expected cell values.

```sql
create table test_table
(
    coord_array          double precision[]                                                                                                   not null,
    wkb_geometry         geometry generated always as (st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[0], coord_array[1]), 4326)) stored                     not null,
    wkt_geometry         text generated always as (st_astext(st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[0], coord_array[1]), 4326))) stored              not null,
    geojson_coord_string jsonb generated always as ((st_asgeojson(st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[0], coord_array[1]), 4326)))::jsonb) stored not null
);
```

Ideally, the insert should only happen with values for `coord_array`

```sql
 insert into test_table (coord_array) values ('{25.0 ,-26.0}')
```

Comment: A strange data model. Perhaps you are looking for a check constraint that makes sure that `coord_array` has two non-NULL elements.

Comment: very true, the `coord_array` can be less than 2 values, which should be rejected. A trigger could solve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem with your code is, that in SQL (and Postgres) arrays start at index 1, not 0. So `coord_array[0]` will always return `null` and thus the expressions of your generated columns always return null, even if two non-null array values are provided.

However, the `not null` constraint on the array itself is not enough. This does not ensure that the array contains (at least) two not null values. To validate that, you need a check constraint.

```
create table test_table
(
    coord_array          double precision[]                                                                                                   not null,
    wkb_geometry         geometry generated always as (st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[1], coord_array[2]), 4326)) stored                     not null,
    wkt_geometry         text generated always as (st_astext(st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[1], coord_array[2]), 4326))) stored              not null,
    geojson_coord_string jsonb generated always as ((st_asgeojson(st_setsrid(st_point(coord_array[1], coord_array[0]), 4326)))::jsonb) stored not null,
    constraint check_coord 
       check (num_nulls(coord_array[1], coord_array[2]) = 0)
);
```

This would allow arrays with more than two elements - but your generated columns won't care as the expressions never use more than the first two elements.